# What's the best way to load a CSX script from a C# application?

Tags: c#, csx

Tools like [dotnet-script](https://github.com/filipw/dotnet-script) and [CSI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2016/january/essential-net-csharp-scripting) allow users to write, compile, and run C# like "scripts" rather than including their code in a complete pre-compiled project. These tools work great for command-line usage, but don't offer much in terms of integrating dynamic C# "scripts" into a larger C# application.

If I have an existing C# application which wishes to load additional classes into its existing namespaces via .csx "scripts", how do I do that? Is it possible?

Comment: Easy with the Roslyn CodeDom provider — https://github.com/aspnet/RoslynCodeDomProvider (not the most granular in the CodeDom form, yet it can easily compile types supporting to C#7 on .NET Framework). It also exposes types to invoke compilation directly from code without needing ASP.NET. The .NET Framework also ships with a CodeDom provider (C# 5).

Comment: (Fun information: the above Roslyn package also contains a csi.exe executable..)

Answer (score 2):

I guess you need to **compile** and **execute** your C# script.

In my experience, I used C# scripts by referencing `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting` (version 3.*) directly.

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting" Version="3.*" />
```

### Compilation

I suggest to use default compilation options:

```cs
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Emit;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting;

// ...
ScriptOptions options = ScriptOptions.Default;
```

Maybe in the future, you'll need to add referenced assemblies to your script compilation.

So you need to compile your `script` (contained in a string variable in the code below):

```cs
byte[] assemblyBinaryContent;

var roslynScript = CSharpScript.Create(script, options);
var compilation = roslynScript.GetCompilation();

compilation = compilation.WithOptions(compilation.Options
    .WithOptimizationLevel(OptimizationLevel.Release)
    .WithOutputKind(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary));

using (var assemblyStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    var result = compilation.Emit(assemblyStream);
    if (!result.Success)
    {
        var errors = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result.Diagnostics.Select(x => x));
        throw new Exception("Compilation errors: " + Environment.NewLine + errors);
    }

    assemblyBinaryContent = assemblyStream.ToArray();
}

GC.Collect(); // it allows to force clear compilation stuff.

Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(assemblyBinaryContent);

var ret = Run(assembly); // see next paragraph
```

### Execution

Obviously you need an entry point to execute your script.
I found out this trickly solution. It works.

```
private object Run(Assembly assembly)
{
    //Execute the script
    var type = assembly.GetType("Submission#0");
    var method = type.GetMethod("<Factory>", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);

    var retTask = method.Invoke(null, new object[] { new object[2] }) as Task<object>;
    return retTask.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```

I hope it can help.